# Send to view.....information from two different databases

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongoose

Below is my code,

I am trying to use information from two different servers and use it on a view called post.

I can successfully use all the information from the database "Car"

but I can't extract information from the Database "House"

On the post view 
I call on the car database like this : {{post.detail}} <--- This works

For the housedata base {{post2.detail}} <---- does not work

```
const Car = require('../database/models/Car') 
const House = require('../database/models/House')

module.exports = async (req, res) => {

const post = await Car.findById(req.params.id)

 const post2 = await House.find({})

        res.render('post', {

                post,
                post2,

        })

}
```

Comment: What do you get if you print the value of `post2` on console?

Comment: [ { createdAt: 2019-03-15T05:06:23.673Z,
    _id: 5c8b32e39c580a3d34c6e696,
    detail:
     '/posts/house (3).mp3',
    __v: 0 },

Comment: post2 is an array of objects, not an object. Try `post2[0].detail`.

Comment: wooooooooooooooooooooooo @TGrif that workedddddddddd

Comment: @TGrif how would you loop through each object in the array ? If you don't know the size of the array ?

Comment: The syntax depends on your rendering engine but I guess with a _for each_ loop.

Comment: @TGrif    I wrote it like this   @each(post in post2)  {{post2[ dont know what to put here].detail}}   AT_endeach      it succesfully loops through the amount of times it needs to but I don't know how to increment post2[0].detail

Answer (score 1):

As @TGrif [mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186602/send-to-view-information-from-two-different-databases/55189113#comment97114147_55186602)

> post2 is an array of objects, not an object. Try `post2[0].detail`.

This works ->  post2[0].detail